# Making a 3 column div component in ionic

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I am trying to build a 3 column div component as follow in ionic but fail to do so. As you all can see, the expected outcome is different and deviate from actual outcome. You all may refer the plunkr file [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/o1Gw0dRoeC0jRyqze0dP?p=preview)

```
 <a class="item item-thumbnail-left" href="#">
      No. 1
      <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/604644048/sign051.gif">
      <span>Title here</span>
      <p>This is a very very very long text that should not concatenate</p>
      <span>More info here</span>
    </a>
```

Expected outcome:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this one.

For more details about row and column in ionic check it out [How to Create Complex Layouts in Ionic](http://www.joshmorony.com/how-to-create-complex-layouts-in-ionic/)

```
<div class = "row">

  <div class = "col text-center">No. 1</div>

  <div class = "col text-center">
     <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/604644048/sign051.gif"></div> 
  <div class = "col text-center"><span>Title here</span>
      <p>This is a very very very long text that should not concatenate</p>
      <span>More info here</span></div>
</div>
```

you can change the size using css and the code works fine in plnkr.

Comment: Hi i try to vertical align the `No. 1` text to center using `vertical-align: middle` but it is not working. Any idea?

Comment: send me in punker up to what you have achieved

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called a flexbox. 
This is one tutorial for how to use flexboxes: 
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/